# Eclipse, Maven: How to import the directory tree into the eclipse-workbench?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to import a Maven directory/project extracted from a zip in `/home/me/Downloads` extracted to `.../Downloads/maven-project` and import it not such into Eclipse that the directory stays at `/home/me/Downloads` but such, that the whole maven directory structure is moved to the eclipse-workbench.

What marks do I have to check for this?

Also - for portability sake (I have the workbench on an USB storage) - if Eclipse loads dependencies, how do I fiddle with the settings that they are also saved in the workbench (given that this is feasible/best-practice) Or is it sufficient to have the dependencies in the JAR file created through maven ?

Comment: What's a maven file? What's an eclipse workbench?

Comment: typo. corrected. content?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve the first question is to open the zip file containing the maven project directly in the Eclipse workspace and import it as a maven project from there.

Concerning the second question, I don't get exactly what you ask, but never make the build of your project dependent on a specific IDE.